# Terraform AWS credentials file not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

In reading the docs over at Terraform it says there are 3 options for finding AWS credientials:

1. Static Credentials( embedded in the source file )
2. Environment variables.
3. From the AWS credentials file

I am trying to have my setup just use the credential file. I've checked that the environment variables are cleared and I have left the relevant variables in Terraform blank.

When I do this and run 'Terraform Plan' I get the error:

> No Valid credential sources found for AWS Provider.

I've even tried adding the location of my credentials file into my provider block and that didn't help either:

```
provider "aws" {
    region  = "${var.region}"
    profile = "${var.profile}"
    shared_credentials_file = "/Users/david/.aws/credentials"
    profile = "testing"
}
```

Is there something I'm missing to get Terraform to read this file and not require environment variables?

Comment: You do upload your code in github or other open-source direcory to publish so your credential is not secure. so do **secure your credential** like this way: `export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="*************"` `export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="="*************"` `export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="us-west-1"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get multiple profiles to work with Terraform make sure that you supply the

```
aws_access_key_id
```

piece to your profile declaration. Each profile should look like this:

```
[profile_name]
aws_access_key=*****
aws_secret_access_key****
aws_access_key_id=*****
```

Technically you don't even need the aws_access_key as it seems the id version is what the underlying aws cli needs. Maybe it was me, but that was never clear in the documents I read.

Comment: I found that more generally Terraform was not good at detecting credentials based on the AWS profile - it needs some hand-holding by specifically passing it the access key id (and possibly the secret too). This can be achieved as you did it by specifying access key id in the profile, alternatively I have had success fixing this problem by specifying it as the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID environment variable.

Answer (score 14):

I tested with `Terraform v0.6.15` and its working fine.

Issue must be with the `profile`. Check the following.  
1. Remove 2 `profile` tags from your provider.

```
provider "aws" {
  region  = "${var.region}"
  shared_credentials_file = "/Users/david/.aws/credentials"
  profile = "testing"
}
```

2. Make sure your credentials file `/Users/david/.aws/credentials` is in the below format, where `testing` is the `profile` you are specifying in `provider "aws"`

```
[testing]
aws_access_key_id = *****
aws_secret_access_key = *****
```

Comment: I removed the extra profile line and verified that the credentials file is of the proper format. I have 2 entries in there. default and testing. I have verified that they work as I've used Boto with this file.

Comment: What is the version of terraform you are running? and, for Boto, did you test with the profile you are using here?

Comment: Terraform v0.6.15 and yes I tested with boto that this profile does indeed work.

Comment: My guess now is that Terraform doesn't work with multiple entries in the credentials file. If i reduce it down to just default it works. If i then just change the name of the profile from default to testing and update my plan it fails.

Comment: I doubt that. I tested with multiple profiles. May be the format is messing up, when you have multiple profiles in the credential file?

Answer (score 3):

If you just need a very quick fix without setting Terraform, 
As suggested in a comment, just type this in your terminal :

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="xxxxxxxxxxxxx" 
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" 
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="your-region-1"
```

Answer (score 1):

(Terraform v0.14.2, macOS 11.0.1)

I needed to do:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=... AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=... terraform plan
```

Which was strange to me, because my ~/.aws is in order, as are my .tf-s.
¯_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same problem with terraform aws provider (2.12.0) and this is how I solved it.

In my case the provider couldn't handle that my default profile in `$HOME/.aws/credentials` did NOT have my access key and secret but it had a "source_profile" in it instead.  It seems the terraform aws provider cannot handle this (yet this works for Java SDK and AWS CLI just fine since I've had this setup for awhile now).

Here is what I had that didn't work, notice the default profile has a role_arn and source_profile:

```
[default]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::<ACCT_ID>:role/readonly
source_profile = account
region = us-east-1

[other-profile]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::<ACCT_ID>:role/other-role
source_profile = account
region = us-east-1

[account]
region = us-east-1
aws_access_key_id=****
aws_secret_access_key=****
```

I changed it to the following which resulted in the aws provider working for me.  Notice I consolidated two profiles into the "default" profile:

```
[other-profile]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::<ACCT_ID>:role/other-role
source_profile = default
region = us-east-1

[default]
region = us-east-1
aws_access_key_id=****
aws_secret_access_key=****
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::<ACCT_ID>:role/readonly
source_profile = default
```

This seems to work fine for the AWS CLI (defaults to the readonly role and supports switching to "other-profile") as well as allowing terraform to read credentials correctly.